# Device /dev/ttyUSB2 is locked

Tags: networking, 18.04, minicom

My GSM modem is attached to ttyUSB2 port but I am not able to access the port for AT commands. When I try to access it I get an error as below:

```
$ sudo minicom
Device /dev/ttyUSB2 is locked.
```

Answer (score 3):

Do `ps -ef` and see if there is any `minicom -s` process running.

If there is then kill that process with `kill -9 pid` where *`pid`* is the PID number given in the output of `ps -ef`. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Read `man minicom`. It says. in part:

```
     B - Lock file location
          On most systems This should be /usr/spool/uucp. GNU/Linux systems use /var/lock. If
          this directory does not exist, minicom will not attempt to use lockfiles.
```

So, look for lock files in `/var/lock` or `/usr/spool/uucp`

Comment: /var/lock  directory exists already and it has following files-                                  .asound.state.lock  LCK..ttyUSB2  ntpdate  subsys  whoopsie

Comment: Adding information in comments is discouraged. It prevents proper formatting, and hides the new info from people and computers that just read questions. Please Edit your question to add information, properly formatted with the `{}` tool.